# Объединение элементов XML документа в разделы подразделений на PHP

Tags: php, xml, xmlparser

Прошу помочь с решением проблемы:

1. Есть XML документ такого формата:

   ```
   <root_group>
       <group display_name='All Contacts' />
       <group display_name='Blacklist' />
       <group display_name='Аппарат управления / Высшее руководство предприятия' ring='Auto' />
    </root_group>
    <root_contact>
       <contact display_name='Л... ......' office_number='4..0 , ' mobile_number='+796..' line='0' ring='Auto' group_id_name='Аппарат управления / Высшее руководство предприятия' />
    </root_contact>
    <root_group>
       <group display_name='All Contacts' />
       <group display_name='Blacklist' />
       <group display_name='Аппарат управления / Высшее руководство предприятия' ring='Auto' />
    </root_group>
    <root_contact>
       <contact display_name='Б........' office_number='4... , ' mobile_number='+7........' line='0' ring='Auto' group_id_name='Аппарат управления / Высшее руководство предприятия' />
    </root_contact>
    <root_group>
       <group display_name='All Contacts' />
       <group display_name='Blacklist' />
       <group display_name='Аппарат управления / Высшее руководство предприятия' ring='Auto' />
    </root_group>
    <root_contact>
       <contact display_name='С......' office_number='4.... , ' mobile_number='+.......9' line='0' ring='Auto' group_id_name='Аппарат управления / Высшее руководство предприятия' />
    </root_contact>
    <root_group>
       <group display_name='All Contacts' />
       <group display_name='Blacklist' />
       <group display_name='Аппарат управления / Высшее руководство предприятия' ring='Auto' />
    </root_group>
    <root_contact>
       <contact display_name='Я......' office_number='.... , ' mobile_number='+.......8' line='0' ring='Auto' group_id_name='Аппарат управления / Высшее руководство предприятия' />
    </root_contact>
    <root_group>
       <group display_name='All Contacts' />
       <group display_name='Blacklist' />
       <group display_name='Аппарат управления / Высшее руководство предприятия' ring='Auto' />
    </root_group>
   ```

   Я привел только малую часть документа (сам документ состоит из более 13000 строк со всеми подразделениями и именами).

Все эти элементы нужно привести к виду чтобы в одной группе были все эти представленные контакты, а также он прошелся по другим группам подразделения и привел их к виду в зависимости от атрибута group_id_name в элементе   и атрибута display_name в элементе :

```
    <root_group>
    <group display_name='All Contacts' />
    <group display_name='Blacklist' />
    <group display_name='Аппарат управления / Высшее руководство предприятия' ring='Auto' />
 </root_group>
 <root_contact>
    <contact display_name='Л.......' office_number='4... , ' mobile_number='+7.....' line='0' ring='Auto' group_id_name='Аппарат управления / Высшее руководство предприятия' />
    <contact display_name='Ш.....' office_number='....' mobile_number='+......7' line='0' ring='Auto' group_id_name='Аппарат управления / Высшее руководство предприятия' />
 </root_contact>
<root_group>
    <group display_name='All Contacts' />
    <group display_name='Blacklist' />
    <group display_name='Руководители' ring='Auto' />
 </root_group>
<root_contact>
    <contact display_name='Л.......' office_number='4... , ' mobile_number='+7.....' line='0' ring='Auto' group_id_name='Руководители' />
    <contact display_name='Ш.....' office_number='....' mobile_number='+......7' line='0' ring='Auto' group_id_name='Руководители' />
 </root_contact>
```

Вот код который я применяю для обработки всего документа, но никак не могу задать условие для цикла чтобы происходил проход по всем строкам файла:

```
    $file=file("output.xml");
$f=fopen("output.xml","w"); 
//flock ($f,LOCK_EX); 
ftruncate ($f,0);
for($i=0;$i<count($file);$i++){
        if($file[i+3]==$file[i+11])
        {
unset($file[i+10]);
unset($file[i+9]);
unset($file[i+8]);
unset($file[i+7]);
unset($file[i+11]);
unset($file[i+12]);
//unset($file[i+5]);
unset($file[i+13]);
//unset($file[i+14]);


    }

}
file_put_contents ('output.xml', implode("", $file));
```

Прошу помочь разобраться в этом вопросе в голову уже ничего не лезет...

Comment: Я думаю вы не с того начали, почему бы вам не распарсить xml используя стандартную библиотеку [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php) при этом?

Comment: Я думал воспользоваться этой библиотекой, но пока не работал с ней. Просто парсинг у меня как раз и использовался при формировании этого XML файла из базы данных 1С битрикс. Теперь мне нужно понять как написать нужное условие для прохода по всему файлу или воспользоваться  библиотекой SimpleXML

Comment: Что-то я вас не очень понял, вы грубо говоря конвертнули базу из mysql в xml, а теперь хотите открыть его чтобы изменить, т.к. он не удовлетворяет требованиям, а что дальше? Почему бы сразу из БД не сформировать в нужном виде файл?

Comment: Обычного доступа к БД нет, так как она находиться внутри сайта на CMS 1C битрикс, с помощью выборок через 1С битрикс я создал новую страницу где он выборкой выбирает нужные контакты и создает файл XML в формате который представленный выше. Теперь мне нужно распарсить этот файл, чтобы в одном группе были все контакты содержащиеся в этой группе. Мне главное получить файл в таком формате с помощью SimpleXML или с помощью других способов.

Comment: Ну всё равно даже если вы не работали с SimpleXML, и если собираетесь данные экспортировать или импортировать в php, лучше воспользоваться этой библиотекой думаю и поработать, чем изобретаться велосипед ) Я с этой библиотекой только экспорт делал, вроде )